# can not import following java libraries

Tags: java

I am not able to import these files in my java projects while using eclipse
can some one helpe me ,i am working hard from many hours to import these but not able to get any solutions, even i reintalled my eclipse and configure my build path, reloaded JRE again change them into 8 , 9 version but could not able to find any solutions , searching solutions on internet but still faile to get any kind of solution
thanks

```
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;
```

Comment: What version of java are you using? If you installed multiple versions, did you correctly update Eclipse to use the new one?

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution:

- ‘Clean’ Your Eclipse Project: Go to Project > Clean in Eclipse
- Refresh your project folder (right click on your project > refresh)
- Re-build your project
- Clean your builds (If using Ant or Maven – clean your builds)
- Recreate your project in Eclipse
- ‘Switch’ Workspace – then Switch back (Eg Change to Debug, then switch back to Java)
- Remove and re-add your JRE:

  - Right Click on your project > properties
  - Click on the Libraries tab
  - Click on the JRE
  - Click remove, then OK
  - Repeat 1-3 again, but add the JRE again

Comment: Thanks Andreas , but still same problem , i tried remove all thing and rebuilt. I also tested with JRE 8 and 9 both but still not going to import any of them

Comment: can some one help me about this issue , i can't be able to import import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;                        i tried to re-install eclipse but still have same problem , i removed all project , refresh my projects but still have same problem